# Test force webapp to throw errors revealing information for hacker attack

Tags: testing, web-applications, angularjs, error-handling

I am curious to see what error messages are sent back in response by my webapp when erroneous condition arise. The reason for my curiosity is that I want to see what information is revealed to the user in such error messages. I came to know that a skilled hacker use a technique to invoke error messages in an attempt to reveal application logic, structure, page names and expected user behaviour. Such information could subsequently be used to assist with more sophisticated attacks on the application. For example, an application error discloses that the web application is being hosted on an Apache web server. This type of information can aid an attacker in the enumeration of the technologies stack in use.

The webapp have few forms with submit buttons on each of them. The webservices are being called through angular RESTful client. I am interested to know the possible ways of how a situation is simulated so that webapp would send an error in the response?

We have these error codes that could possibly come in the response: [more detail](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/http-status-codes/)
Redirection: 300/1/../7, Client Error: 400/1/../17, Server Error: 500/1/../5
How these error codes could be enforced from the server?

Comment: You don't always need to force the app to error to find out which http server it's running on. Looking at the response headers will often display what server it's running on and often the version too!

Comment: @Oliver That's true but I am trimming out the version info from the response header. Unfortunately I couldn't remove the server name because it is inbuilt in the server source code.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered one of the ways is to post a wrong url. To do this put a breakpoint in chrome where rest service call is being made, locate the url attribute in post call, tweak it and resume. Did I get any information in the error message I was looking for? Yes! Got the message "HTTP Status 500" along with Jboss server and its version information in it.